# How to save switch setting in Android using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, uiswitch

I have a need to save the position of a switch (actually 6 switches) as part of user preferences in Android using Kotlin.

I have written the code in Java with no problems, but this code needs to be in Kotlin. 
I was thinking to use shared preferences as in Java, and have successfully produced code to save the state of one switch. However, when I write code to add a second switch, the first switch takes control of the additional switches and their state is saved as the same as the first. Additionally, all subsequent switches will reproduce the same.
I have tried the Kotlin.org code converter/translator, but that is producing a bunch of jabber that I have to clean up before I can compile, then find out that the translated code is likely incomplete.

```
    private fun onSwitch() {

    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()


    push_switch1.isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_SWITCH, false)
    push_switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked){
            editor.putBoolean(PREF_SWITCH, push_switch1.isChecked)
            editor.putBoolean(PREF_SWITCH, true)
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Push Notification ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            editor.putBoolean(PREF_SWITCH, false)
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Push Notification Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        //editor.apply()
    }
    email_switch1.isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_SWITCH, false)
    email_switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked){
            editor.putBoolean(PREF_SWITCH, email_switch1.isChecked)
            editor.putBoolean(PREF_SWITCH, true)
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Email Notification ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }else{
            editor.putBoolean(PREF_SWITCH, false)
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Email Notification OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        //editor.apply()
    }
    editor.apply()
```

This is a preferences page and each on/off switch turns on or off a specific user preference. Additionally, the switch state needs to persist to keep the user's settings.

Comment: You have to apply changes to the Editor inside the each listener. It's the same thing in Java.

Comment: You should have different keys for your preferences. You are always using the same `PREF_SWITCH` key in the code above, regardless of the switch. Each switch should be associated with a given key.

Comment: FYI you don't need online code converters, Android Studio and Intellij IDEA will automatically convert your Java code into Kotlin if you paste it into a .kt file.

Comment: @Egor Thank you for that.

Comment: @Wang Yes, you are correct! I got so caught up in making sure that the Kotlin code was correct that I didn't change, or add additional keys for the other switches. Thank you for the response.

Comment: @TheWanderer Thanks for the reply. I was trying different things to try and figure out my problem. At the time, this was the most recent code I had to enter. And yes, you are correct "editor.apply()" MUST be in each listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of your switch push_switch1 and email_switch1 is using the same Preference KEY which is PREF_SWITCH.

You need to add unique Preference KEY for each of your switch. 
Add PREF_SWITCH_PUSH and PREF_SWITCH_EMAIL preferences.
Then try this...

```
private fun onSwitch() {

    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()


    push_switch1.isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_SWITCH_PUSH, false)
    push_switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked){
            editor.putBoolean(PREF_SWITCH_PUSH, true)
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Push Notification ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else {
            editor.putBoolean(PREF_SWITCH_PUSH, false)
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Push Notification Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        editor.apply()
    }
    email_switch1.isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_SWITCH_EMAIL, false)
    email_switch1.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked){
            editor.putBoolean(PREF_SWITCH_EMAIL, true)
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Email Notification ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }else{
            editor.putBoolean(PREF_SWITCH_EMAIL, false)
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Email Notification OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        editor.apply()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for seeing that. I realized what I had done about an hour after I posted this question. I was completely caught up in the Kotlin code that I didn't consider changing or adding additional keys for the additional switches.